# How to control a large number of devices with an Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm doing some initial research on a project I have in mind. I am super new to all this Arduino stuff so taking it slow and gathering lots of info.

I want to control around 1000 small linear actuators to push/pull a very small load. The purpose of this question is specifically how to manage that many devices. The devices won't ever need to start their own transmissions so the Arduino can get everything done by polling them ...I hope ...and I don't think it would be a lot of data to each device but I imagine overall it may be. I want to control each device at the "same" time, all with the same cabling distance (around 2m). From what I can tell, a [**CANbus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus)  is exactly what I need, where I can assign a unique ID to each device (node) and then write some code to control the network array.

In summary, is a CANbus the ideal bit of hardware here to work with an Arduino to control in real time such a high number of devices?

Thanks,
Nick.

Edit: Sorry for the vagueness, I'm very new to all this so really just looking for keywords to help scope my project out before asking more complex specific questions. It's difficult to formulate what's in my head to experienced people without sounding like a goose. I'm experienced on the software side, but the hardware i/o is all brand new.

Ultimately, I am wanting to sample a grey scale image/sequence of images and depending on the value sampled in a 0-255 range which is mapped to the extension capabilities of each actuator to extend/contract in that pixel.

Hope that is more helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps edit your question to clarify some things.  Why do your devices (linear actuators) need to send any data to the Arduino?  Does "control each device at the "same" time" mean you want all the devices to move simultaneously, or just that all of them are in-circuit ready to be controlled?  If the latter, what are your desired and required limits on reaction times and position update frequency?

Comment: CAN bus is **a** solution but possibly overkill for what you want. How are actuators powered and switched. On/off or linear control.  They will need power switching . CAN bus will require node electronics per actuator. CAN bus physical layer is almost identical to RS422 hardware and you can implement multi slave R@422 hardware very cheaply. 1000 devices will require proper design of bus loading for any system and depending on whether control is open loop (one way) or closed loop (to and fro data) a star network topology may suit. More information will help people provide better answers.

Comment: @jwpat7 ...have added more project details. The actuators won't ever need to communicate back to the Arduino ...yes I mean move each device  simultaneously and at the number i am investigating, I think will need some special attention in the design.

Comment: @Russell McMahon ...thanks very much for your reply. I have updated my question with some more info but your reply is super helpful and helps me expand my research. I have no time limit and this is a learning experience for me so thanks for your suggestions, I can further look into what you have mentioned. I have allot of programming experience but not for devices or in electrical design.

Comment: What kind of control signal do your actuators expect?

Comment: An ordinary (ATmega-based) Arduino is **the wrong choice** for this job.  Consider you would use half your RAM just keeping track of the desired state of each actuator.  There are far more capable processors at similar price points for the bare chip, and actually quite a bit cheaper assembled on a board.  Of course you should start by proving your concept with only a handful of actuators, but you might as well start on a platform that is a plausible fit for your goal.

Comment: @Edgar Bonet ...that's completely open at the moment. I've not settled on anything in particular. Very early stages so am also looking into what would be the best fit. The biggest question I have at the moment is, can I control that many devices simultaneously. If you have any suggestions, would be super to hear them.

Comment: @Chris Stratton ...this is my number one concern at the moment for me as a total novice. Allot of devices and yeah will need to track where they are in realtime. I do plan to start with a proof of concept but am no where near that yet. I want to collect as much info first so I can put a design together. Would REALLY like to hear your suggestions on what might be more capable. Thanks very much.

Comment: First thing to do is figure out what it takes to control a single device in the manner you need.  Then think about the required per-device electronics, as that is what will kill your cost/complexity.  You might look at WS2812/etc LED strings for inspiration, or even (if you current requirements are tiny) drivers.  In terms of the master controller, the decision will be driven a lot by the complexity of decision making.  If that requires something the power of a PC, you'll be looking at a comparable embedded board (Beaglebone, etc).  If not, probably an ARM Cortex M0, M3, or M4.

Comment: @Chris Stratton ...excellent this is a great start. Thanks very much. Will start looking into these options. Much appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Can you expand info on time requirements? How long is acceptable to change 1000 units? How many max can change at once? How important is synchronisation of movements? Afuller explanation of what it does and how may help ensure answer matches need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a suggestion, certainly not the only possible approach.

**Step 1**: Get a handful of small linear actuators *with a builtin
controller*. Some actuators have no controller, and will require one
H-bridge and one analog input each. You do not want these. I have seen
some actuators with built-in controllers that can be driven just like
servos, I would suggest you get some of those. At this point you should
carefully look at costs when choosing the actuators.

**Step 2**: Learn how to drive those actuators from an AVR-based
Arduino, like an Arduino Uno, using the Servo library. I believe you can
drive up to 12 actuators with a single Arduino.

**Step 3**: Drive them using *two* Arduinos in a master-slave
configuration. The master would be a beefy Arduino, like a Mega or a
Due. It would send commands to the slave using, say, an I2C bus. After
sending the set points for the actuators, it would send a "go" order to
the I2C broadcast address. The slave would be the Uno. It would
interpret the commands and actually drive the actuators.

**Step 3b**: Change the master's program to *pretend* it is controlling
many slaves, and a total of 1000 actuators. In reality, all the
slaves would have the same I2C address: that of the unique slave
actually available. This will tell you whether your master is powerful
enough for the job, and you will see how the performance scales.

**Step 3c**: Optimize the slave's code. Try to have it work with an
8 MHz clock, and use as little flash and RAM as possible.

**Step 4**: Replace the slave Arduino with a bare AVR chip. You will
have to learn how to program it via ISP, but the information is widely
available. An Uno is an ATmega328P at heart, but depending on the
program size, you may get away with an ATmega48A, which is the same
thing only with less memory, and dirty cheap. Or even with a still
cheaper ATtiny. If you can make your program work with an 8 MHz
clock, then use the internal oscillator, which will save you having to
buy an external resonator. All this is to keep the costs reasonable.

**Step 4b**: Test, test, test. Last chance to change your mind before
committing big bucks.

**Step 5**: If everything works at this stage, it's time to scale up.
The same master Arduino, and one bare AVR for each dozen actuators, each
with it's own I2C address.

Comment: Thanks very much Edgar ...as good a place than any to start. Very much appreciated :) cheers

Comment: @NickvanDiem: I just added a few sub-steps.

Comment: .@Edgar Bonet ...worthy additions, thank you :) ...do you offer a consultanting service for Arduino projects?

Comment: Not formally, but if I can help, and you provide some contact info in your profile, I would be happy to give a try.

Comment: .@Edgar Bonet ...great have updated! Ping me a msg